# Screen mirroring on pc

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, android-pc, screen-mirroring

I was wondering if there is a way to mirror my screen of the phone to my pc using the same wi fi connection, like you can do with a smart tv; Do I need to download any special app or program for pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try AllCast witch only require a working Wi-Fi connection.

It works pretty great for me (Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 Pro, Android 6.0) :

1. Download [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.mirror)
2. On your PC, in Chrome, install [AllCast Receiver](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allcast-receiver/hjbljnpdahefgnopeohlaeohgkiidnoe)

Make sure both your phone and laptop are connected on the same wireless network and then :

3. Open Mirror Beta and select your computer

AllCast Receiver will show up on your computer mirroring your Android screen.
Hope this will work for what you need.